# Yii2 проект после переноса на хостинг reg.ru не отображаются картинки. В OSPanel (локально) они на месте

Tags: yii2, openserver

Проект созданный на Yii2 с БД MySQL был загружен на reg.ru хостинг http://wscb.online
Если локально с OpenServer проблем с картинками не было, то после загрузки на хостинг вместо картинок лишь рамки.
Наличие файлов с изображениями проверил - они там есть, сливал обратно, файлы прилетают. В БД даже загружаются новые, проблема лишь с выводом в браузер.
В режиме разработчика дописываешь путь к файлу картинки (добавляешь в путь /web и изображение тут же прогружается) - такой пробовал вариант грубого решения.
Вопросом осталось почему этот же проект(с невидимыми фото на хостинге) выгрузив обратно в локальный OpenServer картинки появляются на страницах. Хотя проект один и тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если перейдете по любой ссылке на неподгруженное изображение (их легко найти в консоли браузера, они там с красненьким текстом GET 404 not found) - заметите, что ошибку возвращает вам `Yii2` с текстом `Page not found`, это говорит о том что конфигурация http-сервера (скорее всего на хостинге Apache) не настроена должным образом, и перенаправляет любые запросы к `index.php` в папке `web`.

В директории public_html у вас должен быть`.htaccess` настроенный подобным образом:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Возможно достаточно в папку `web` положить файл `.htaccess` с содержимым:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление, оно оказалось верным и помогло разобраться с проблемой! В корне проекта в файле .htaccess закомментировал строку #RewriteRule . /web/index.php и фотографии отобразились. Более никаких манипуляций не потребовалось для решения этой задачи. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что ваш веб-сервер настроен неправильно. В качестве рута должна быть указанна папка web, а у вас на папку выше.
Если вы используете nginx, то это делается так:

```
root /var/www/html/web;
```

Поэтому проект один и тот же, но картинки доступны по другому пути.